# Resolve conflicts before Merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-conflict

Кто-нибудь знает как через командную строку исправить этот конфликт слияния разом, а не вручную?
Я прикрепила фото. Раньше с таким [image: введите сюда описание изображения] не сталкивалась. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Зачем вы вообще добавляете *.pyc файлы в git?

Comment: я просто коммичу свой репозиторий

Comment: А надо не «просто коммитить», а убирать *.pyc файлы за ненадобностью, тогда и конфликтов не будет

Comment: как мне их игнорировать((

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9#r_ignoring

Comment: класс, спасибо.